# Error in native method using Box2d LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to write a little game using LibGDX and I use Box2D in this purpose. So I'm trying to add a new projectile to the world, but there comes into true an error with the following stacktrace:

[image: stacktrace]

There's a code snippet where the error comes from:

```
shooting.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int p, int b) {
            float degree2 = MathUtils.atan2(shooting.getKnobPercentY(), moving.getKnobPercentX());
            if(shooting.getKnobPercentX() != 0 || shooting.getKnobPercentY() != 0) {
                if(core.netDisp.currentSession.choosenGun.shotAvailable) {
                    core.netDisp.currentSession.choosenGun.cooldown = core.netDisp.currentSession.choosenGun.velocity;
                    core.netDisp.currentSession.choosenGun.shotAvailable = false;
                    Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "1");
                    Projectile.bodyDef.position.set(myBody.getPosition().x + 50, myBody.getPosition().y + 50);
                    Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "2");
                    Body newShell = world.createBody(Projectile.bodyDef);
                    Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "3");
                    Projectile nukekteper = new Projectile(core.netDisp.currentSession.nickname, core.netDisp.currentSession.choosenGun.damage, degree2);
                    Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "4");
                    newShell.createFixture(nukekteper.fixDef);
                    Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "5");
                    newShell.setUserData(nukekteper);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The program stops before "Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "5")", but after "Gdx.app.log("my new bullet", "4")". This means that the problematic method is "newShell.createFixture(nukekteper.fixDef)"
There's a code of class "Projectile":

```
public class Projectile {

public static BodyDef bodyDef;
public FixtureDef fixDef;
private ParticleEffect appearance;
public String owner;
public float damage;

static {
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
}

public Projectile(String owner, float damage, float a) {
    appearance = new ParticleEffect();
    appearance.load(Gdx.files.internal("particles/bullet.p"), Gdx.files.internal("particles"));

    bodyDef.angle = a;

    fixDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixDef.density = 0.1f;
    fixDef.friction = 0.1f;
    fixDef.restitution = 0.6f;
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(1.0f);
    fixDef.shape = shape;
    shape.dispose();

    appearance.start();
    appearance.getEmitters().first().getAngle().setHigh(a * radiansToDegrees - 10, a * radiansToDegrees + 10);
    appearance.getEmitters().first().getAngle().setLow(a * radiansToDegrees - 10, a * radiansToDegrees + 10);
}

public void draw(Batch batch, float delta, float x, float y) {
    appearance.draw(batch, delta);
    appearance.getEmitters().first().setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - x, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - y);
}
```

}

Comment: In 90% of cases, these errors occur because you modify the world during updating. Do not create or destroy bodies on world step (for example - in contact listener's methods).

Comment: I changed the code so there's nothing like bodies could be created or destroyed during updating. But the same error still appears. What's wrong?

Comment: I honestly don't have the time to go through your code, but some links might help: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93185/libgdx-box2d-crashing http://magory.net/libgdx-box2d-how-to-avoid-crashes/